# Keep all states when going back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have multiple pages in my Angular app that the user can change quite a bit, i.e. open tabs and pills, modals, etc. Let's say, for example, they open a modal and then click a link in that modal which leads them to another page. On that other page, when they go back in their browser history, I'd want them to see the first page the way they left it, i.e. with the modal open, not how it looks when you reload it.

I am using ui-router with Angular 1.4.3.

So far I have looked into the following links:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/63
- https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/562

...but they don't seem to be quite what I need. And I'm not even sure how to google this.

Another example for this is when a user enters something in a search bar, then clicks on a result which leads to a new page. When they go back, they would have to enter the search again, which is not the greatest experience.

Comment: you can always try to manage all this little thing with some variables within an object stored in the localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a service to store page state

Rather than storing page state and user input on the `$scope`, store it on a persistent service that is injected into the page controller along with the `$scope`.

Store a reference to the service on the `$scope`:

```
myApp.service('MyPageStateService', function() {
    this.someProperty = 'some initial state';
});

myApp.controller('MyPageController', function($scope, MyPageStateService) {
    $scope.state = MyPageStateService;
});
```

and from the page template access data stored on the persistent state service:

```
<div ng-controller="MyPageController">
    <p>My page state is {{state.someProperty}}</p>
</div>
```

When navigating back to this page within the app, the controller will get a new `$scope` but the same instance of `MyPageStateService`.

Comment: That won't suffice. I can't store all the minuscule details of user interaction. And it's not very scalable, either. If I add new things to the page, I don't want to have to extend that service. I'm wondering if maybe there already is some browser API I can leverage for this.

Comment: How are you currently storing all those 'miniscule details of user interaction'?

Comment: I'm not. And ideally, I wouldn't have to.

Comment: The UI state has to be stored somewhere. Typically in an angular app, those details are all stored on the scope via bindings (e.g. with `ng-model="something"`). The only change here is that all bindings would be prefixed with `state.` (`ng-model="state.something"`).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your scalability concerns. This approach doesn't require any extra logic except one-line service registration per page. Anything else you would need to add to the service would be on the controller otherwise - so you aren't adding any extra overhead, just moving logic from the controller to the service.

Comment: If I have 10 pills on the page I don't want to have to remember which pills the user opened. I'm wondering if there is some way for the browser to remember all that.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [sticky states](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/sticky). They are not limited to forward/back navigation, this gives some consistency to them.

If this behaviour is not desirable anywhere but forward/back, I guess it can be done by doing [$stickyState.reset('...')](https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras/issues/162#issuecomment-73370562) on `$stateChangeStart` for everything except the adjacent state.